# Not being able to Migrate new app because 'Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency userSocial.0001_initial on database 'default'

Tags: django, django-migrations

I created a Django root, where I created one app to access my database and created all the necessary models, serializers, views and urls to access it as an API on my web app. After finishing that Django App with a PostgreSQL DB and a Web App. I wanted to create 2 new Apps in the same root to access the same database but for a different use scenario and a different Web App. The first one has the ability to do everything View, Delete and Update my database, this next two apps are for creating Users and creating a small Social Media with posts and comments.

However after getting the UserModel ready and set up the models for the Social Media App, I am getting this error:

```
PS C:\codeacademy\O_lar\o_lar_db> python manage.py migrate           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\codeacademy\O_lar\o_lar_db\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\codeacademy\O_lar\o_lar_db\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 120, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\rodil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 327, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency userSocial.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

It talks about admin so I tried to do
`python.manage.py migrate admin zero`

But with no avail.

I don't really want to delete all the migrations folders because I don't want to possible damage my database and all the work I've done to the other App, but I am mainly a Front-End Engineer so that's me thinking that I could damage it If I do that. I've tried deleting the migrations on the new Apps, and it lets me makemigrations but once I try to migrate the same error appears.

I am happy to delete all the data in the database, as long as it's structure and everything on the first app I created doesn't get damage and makes me code everything again.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the actual data itself, you can delete the database and all migration folders. The migrations tell the database how to get the current state of the database to the state you define in your models.py. So if you do not change models.py in your first app, you'll be fine.

The models define the structure of your database. So after deleting all mentioned stuff it will create an initial migration. Here, as the error tells you it is important to migrate User concerning apps first.

Comment: Just for me to understand better the process, like I said this really isn't my area so I am kind of learning as I go with a small project. Do I need to code all the logic regarding the users first on all apps before making the migration or just the start and then I can add new logic as I go?

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) section will help you. Only the initial migration where you define `AUTH_USER_MODEL` needs to run before the other apps. If you want to add a new field to your model lateron you can do that. Linked section explains better than me, though.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment and explanation, I haven't tried it yet but I believe it makes sense and it should work since from other people that had similar problems and their solution was to basically delete DB and migrations, I was just scared I would lose my work and thats why I decided to post. Have an amazing day